# Case usage in R:Count number of events from Table 2 when case in Table 1 satisfy specific restrictions

Tags: r, loops, case

The DF for Table 1 is like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c('001','001','002','003', '003', '003'), 
                  date = c('2015-05-23', '2015-07-29', '2015-08-08', '2015-06-10', '2015-10-12', '2015-11-15'), 
                  date_last = c('2015-01-20', '2015-05-23', '2015-05-15', '2015-01-20', '2015-06-10', '2015-10-12'))
```

And the DF for Table 2 is like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Event = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 
                  Event_date = c('2015-01-21', '2015-01-21', '2015-03-29', '2015-08-12', '2015-10-12'))
```

what I want to get is to get case when `df1$date_last` < `df2$Event_date` < `df1$date`, then count(Event) as 1 and sum up how many events during the time period. The ideal result I want to have is like the following:

```
df3 <- data.frame(ID = c('001','001','002','003', '003', '003'), 
                  date = c('2015-05-23', '2015-07-29', '2015-02-08', '2015-06-10', '2015-10-12', '2015-11-15'), 
                  date_last = c('2015-01-20', '2015-05-23', '2015-05-15', '2015-01-20', '2015-06-10', '2015-10-12'), 
                  number_of_events = c(3,1,0,3,1,0))
```

Anyone know the R code for this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that all your dates are of class date. You simply to this by putting `as.Date()` around the columns in the creation of the data frames.

First define a function with `x` being a vector with end and start date respectively, and `y` being a vector with dates that should be checked.

```
nr_events_in_between <- function(x, y) sum(x[2] < y & x[1] > y)
```

Apply this to all rows in `df1` and you get the `number_of_events` column.

```
apply(df1[ ,c('date', 'date_last')], 1, nr_events_in_between,  df2[,'Event_date'])
```

(Note that for the second row the value is 0 not 1 as you state in the example for `df3`)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. I followed exactly what you said, but I only got NAs for all my records. The dates are all fixed as you reminded. Do you know what might be the reason?

Comment: My guess is that one of the date columns is not converted to date. Could you do a `str()` of both of the data.frames to check if all three are of class `Date`?